# How to check where Debug output is coming from?

Tags: troubleshooting, debug

I was debugging my windows service application through Debug messages.

To view debug message, I was using [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) (from SysInternals). However I am getting flooded with following Keyboard output on the output (which I found out how to filter out).

Is there a way to find out which application is responsible for generating a debug output?
And is anyone familiar with the message shown below?

[image]

**Answer** (Thanks [heavyd](https://superuser.com/questions/35815/how-to-check-where-debug-output-is-coming-from/35818#35818))
Found the culprit responsible for that verbose output, and slowing down my machine considerably.  Now I need to find out where this guy came from.

**UPDATE]**
OKay, this is a driver for Lenovo Ultra Nav keyboard. That's it.  This guy is out...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with that particular message, however in the Options menu you can select "Win32 PIDs".  The PID then should show up in the debug print in brakets like this:

```
[PID] MakeCode = 2d, vkCode = 58, State = 80
```

You can then use ProcessExplorer to determine the application by its proccess ID.

Comment: @heavyd: Right on!